# What's a good language for linux system administration?

Tags: linux

I've created a set of nifty set of Makefiles for repeating the steps to provision and maintain many AWS clusters.

The benefits of make have been:

- the bulk of the execution are various shell commands
  These are clearly specified and easy to maintain within make.
- the whole process fails if any individual step fails (unlike bash)
- I can bake parameterized commands into make recipes (with hackery)
- I can specify dependencies to these commands (with hackery)

However, through much of this I've been feeling like make is a poor match for the task. Parameterized commands are a terrible hack implemented by calling make calling itself again with new parameters. Conditional execution is horrible in make. Simple tasks like
   if CHECK_SERVER_STARTED(params) then START_SERVER(params);
   COLLECT_DATA_FILES(params)
   if server_was_stopped_at_the_start(params) then STOP_SERVER(params);

Also, dependency tracking using files is a terrible idea.

There must be a better way. Is there a good language I can have:

- shell commands trivially run (ideally part of the language) (i.e. not Python, Perl)
- conditionals, branching, failure-case handling, etc... are all built in
- loops
- local variables (or at least something like a stack, so that I can call a function
  and not have thing piss all over my global variables).

Comment: Configuration Managment.  Puppet, Cheft, Salt, Ansible, etc...

Answer (score 8):

This hurts to read... Sooo complex!

Yes, of course there is a better way. Part of being a *pro* is keeping abreast of changes in technology. [**Configuration management**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) is what you're looking for, and has been around for a number of years. Most of your problems have been solved.